# Create a help command that sends a different message for every other command

Tags: discord.js

I need help making my commands description.
At the moment I'm manually making an embed for every command, and it takes a lot of time if you have 50+ commands. I've seen something like this:

```js
exports.help = {
  name: 'help',
  description: 'Shows all the commands in the bot',
  usage: 'rhelp',
  inHelp: 'yes'
};
```

How can I implement that into an embed? It should look like this:
[image: Embed picture]

What I type to get it `rhelp help`

Comment: Hi, I've edited your question. I've improved the formatting and added the image. I've also edited the title, so that it's more understandable

Comment: @FedericoGrandi thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as I mis-understood the question.
You would like to know HOW to get the object.
Well there is a couple methods of doing this.

Lets say in `help.js` is your example object
And in `test.js` is another object *slightly* changed.

this is how I would proceed.

### Method "pre-loading"

When I do this method, It's because I have like 15 commands or more.
And in each command there's an object like this

```
 module.exports = {
     help: {
       name: 'help',
       description: 'Shows all the commands in the bot',
       usage: 'rhelp',
       inHelp: 'yes'
     },
     run: function(args){
       //Run the "help" command
     }
 }
```

And each command has the above. All the info and a `.run()`;
So then in a new file what I usually call `command_manager.js` Since it manages all the commands.

So in the main file I usually check if the message *starts with the prefix* and then pass it down to `command_manager` But sometimes I let the command manager deal with that. But the important part is that the command_manager has a `.load()` that get's called when the bot turns on.

```
var prefix = "r";
var filesToLoad = ["help","test"];
module.exports = {
    load:function(){
        for(var i =0;i<filesToLoad.length;i++){
            var file = require(fileToLoad[i]+".js");
            //some code to make sure file is correct command.
            this[fileToLoad[i]] = file;
        }
    }
    runCommand:function(message){
       var split = message.content.toLowerCase().split(" ");
       split[0].substring(prefix.length,split[0].length);
       var commandName = split.shift();

       switch(commandName){
           case "help": this.help.run(message,split,this);break;
           case "test": this.test.run();break;
       }
    }
}
```

Now that command manager works inside the `help.js`
the `.run` function needs to be like this:

```
 function(message,args,cmdManager){
      if(cmdManager[args[0]] != null){
           //using my function from my old answer
           turnToEmbed(cmdManager[args[0].help]);
      }
 }
```

I would supply other methods. But in my opinion they aren't as great and this answer is getting quite long.

Answer (score 0):

So make sure you have the right object:

```js
var help = {
  name: 'help',
  description: 'Shows all the commands in the bot',
  usage: 'rhelp',
  inHelp: 'yes'
};
```

And let's turn the above into an embed.
Prob the nicest way would be:

```js
function turnToEmbed(object) {
  return new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setColor("RANDOM")
    .setTitle("Some handy dandy info on: "+object.title)
    .addField("Description:",object.description,true)
    .addField("Usage:",object.usage,true)
    .setFooter("And voila :P");
}
message.channel.send({ embed: turnToEmbed(help) });
```

Note: if I misunderstood and you want to know how to **get** the correct object, let me know.

Comment: now lets say for the first code its in my kick.js file but i want to transfer that to my help.js file to make the embed. so when a person types rhelp kick it will send the description of the kick.js into an embed in the help.js file if you know what Im saying lol.